# Docker hang whenever I create a file in mount point

Tags: docker, macos

On my Macos, I start a container

```
docker run -v /Users/username/myd:/home/myd -it python:3 /bin/bash
```

Then in the directory `/Users/username/myd` in my local machine, I create a file name a.txt. After that, in the docker environment, I do `ls` at `/home/myd` then the docker hangs forever. I have restarted my computer, restarted docker repeatedly, and it always happens. Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while. I have figured out that I have to check the box `Use gRPC FUSE for file sharing` in Docker desktop setting.